# Finding total number of ways for some conditions

Tags: math, combinations, permutation

There is a particular type of problem for which I need some help to understand it properly.
Lets look at an example.
Suppose we are given an integer n.
We have to find the number of possible pairs (say a and b) such that the given conditions are fulfilled-

1. 1<=a<=b<=n
2. f(a) < f(b)

where f(a)=sum of digits of a

Now I understand that instead of counting the possible solutions, we will try to find the number of ways to form two numbers such that the above 3 conditions are fulfilled. We will start from the one's place and go on from there.

But how to proceed after that?

How to determine that we have to stop now??

How to check that the above conditions are fulfilled at each step?
For e.g What digit we choose for the thousand's place will depend on the digits chosen for the hundred's and the one's place.

This is a pretty common type of a problem in competitive programming and I want to learn the proper method to solve it.

Comment: Bruteforcing will be an option.

Comment: Brute force will always lead to time limit exceeded. The method I mentioned above is pretty efficient but I just can't seem to get a proper understanding of it.

Comment: For simplicity why not eliminate rule 2 and make rule 1 to be 1<=a<b<=n ?

Comment: Which "time limit" do you mean? Have you tried brute force and it failed in some way? What is your code? Have you considered finding a quick way, given `c`, to find the numbers `a` for which `f(a)=c`?

Comment: Cory, suggestion accepted. 
And Time limit refers to the time limit exceeded message in competitive programming. Our program is given a specific amount of time to complete the given task. If it does not, time limit exceeded message pops up.

And by brute force I mean, subtracting 1 and going through all the possibilities which surely is not an optimal method.

Comment: @Cory, that simplification does not work for some cases. For example,  a=29, b=30 would acceptable under your simplification, but it does not meet condition 2.

Comment: @MatthewPope I had edited the question. Before the edit, 2nd condition was 
a<b which was already contained in condition 1. So removed that. That's what cory was talking about.